# android chrome webview not working

Tags: android, webview

I tried to open url in webview using chrome but my application crashes why so :
what shoudl i do to call url in chrome webview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//Code begins here
 private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
 private WebView mWebView;
 private Context context;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
    String packageName = "com.android.chrome";

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    browserIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //Activity context = null;
    List<ResolveInfo> activitiesList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            browserIntent, -1);
    if(activitiesList.size() > 0) {
        // Found the browser on the device, launch it
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
    } else {
        // The browser isn't installed, so we should prompt the user to get
        Intent playStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        playStoreIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName));
        playStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(playStoreIntent);
    }


}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
}
```

Comment: update whole code, check now

Comment: See below my answer, it works 100%

Comment: My updated answer will surely help, I tested it

Comment: yeah it works,  but user gets out of app , ie chrome browser gets opened  there, i want to open it inside application with no address bar like in my case just like webview

Comment: I have given the answer of the above problem, Make separate question for another requirement.

Comment: yeah but i want to open it inside app, now link opens outside app in browser , how to make it open inside app like webview

Comment: @RIT sorry had gone out for luch voted and tick and will raise new question for my requiremnet

Comment: Ok no issues, make separate question for each problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine, See my answer

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
//Code begins here

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    String packageName = "com.android.chrome";

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    browserIntent.setPackage(packageName);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    //Activity context = null;
    List<ResolveInfo> activitiesList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            browserIntent, -1);
    if(activitiesList.size() > 0) {
        // Found the browser on the device, launch it
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    } else {
        // The browser isn't installed, so we should prompt the user to get
        Intent playStoreIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        playStoreIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+packageName));
        playStoreIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(playStoreIntent);
    }


}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
}
```

Comment: i have chrome installed on my tablet but when i run above application it opens google play why so

Comment: Accept answers & upvote those if its helpful, this is how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 1):

```
    Activity context = null;
```

assign it to your `Activity`. 
You pass the `Activity` context null then thats way it crashes .

Comment: what have i to write there